# PHP get 5 additional characters after a specified string of a particular page and list them

Tags: php, html, pdf

**Note: I have edited the post on 2017/08/20**

I'm trying to obtain a list of product page's URL that goes "www.example.com/product/11111/".

There are over 200 different products available and each of them has its own product page, I want to print out each product in a PDF file.

On "www.example.com/productlist/", there are URLs that lead to each product's page.

So, what I'm trying to do is

1. Obtain URLs that I need from "www.example.com/productlist/"
2. Generate PDF files of URLs that I have obtained

Comment: To allow others to help you, please provide some info on your website setup and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable sample of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or whatever you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insufficient Information:** You did not provide me with much information about the code you already have and how the website will get the 200 URLs, so I can't write the whole code because it depends on the way your website will get the links from.

If you explain more about how the website is supposed to get the links, I will help you put them into an array and save them into a file and implement the rest of the code!

**1-) Thing I understood is getting the last 5 characters**

As you just want the last 5 characters, not the whole last part, you can do something like this.

```
    $string = "http://example.com/folder/example/1234567"; //your link
    $characters = strlen($string);  //gets the characters count
    $letters = 5;  //edit 5 to show more or less manually
    $code = substr($string, $characters - $letters, $characters);

    echo $code; //will show the last 5 characters
```

I am always here to help. Good luck!

Comment: @HelloWorld Any News ?

Comment: Hello. Sorry I'm new to SO and couldn't figure out how to move forward. I edited my question. I hope that will explain the point. If not, please let me know. Thank you very much for helping me out. I appreciate that you are spending your time for me!

Answer (score 0):

Start with parse_url().

```
$parts=parse_url("http://example.com/folder/example/12345");
```

That will give you an array with a handful of keys. The one you are looking for is path.

Split the path on / and take the last one.

```
$path_parts=explode('/', $parts['path']);
```

Your random numbers can now be stored like:

```
$number = $path_parts[count($path_parts)-1].
```